# What does this netbeans icon mean?

Tags: netbeans, unresolved-external

After creating a web service client in a web application on NetBeans 7.0, the icon of the project shows a warning sign and then the label turns red. Now the web service client does not work as its supposed to and does not give me any messages as regards its failure. So i was wondering if the icon could point me in the right direction but unfortunately I dont know what it means. this is the Icon:
[image: web application icon showing warning]

If anyone knows one or two things about this icon would be great to share. Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally when a project's icon turns red it means that there are unresolved external dependencies.  If you right click on the project and look at the bottom of the context menu, you will see an item called `Resolve Reference Problems` (corrected based on comment).  Clicking on that will open up a list of external dependencies that are unresolved and give you an opportunity to show NetBeans where they are located; perhaps pointing NetBeans to a `.jar` file or a library.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I checked as you directed. The context menu is "Resolve Reference Problems"...

Comment: Your welcome.  Thanks for the correction, I've corrected this in the answer